# Error bind message supplies 1 parameters, but prepared statement "" requires 0. How can I fix this error?

Tags: javascript, sql, postgresql

I am working with javascript and getting my data from a sql file
I would like to make my formatting and syntax is correct and make sure I am not missing any key arguments so it can work when I run through Postman.

I need for the following format to be returned when campground name is returned:

```
 "campgrounds": [{
        "campground": "Three Rivers Petroglyph Site",
        "location": "Lincoln, NM",
        "maxlength": "25"
  }]
```

This is what I have written:

```js
app.get('/search', async (req, res) => {
    let searchTerm = req.query.name;
    console.log(`Search for ${searchTerm}`);

    try { const template = "SELECT name, location, maxlength FROM campgrounds";
          const response = await pool.query(template, [searchTerm]);
                if (searchTerm === template.name) {
                        res.json({campgrounds: searchTerm, location: req.query.location, maxlength: req.query.maxLength});
                }

    } catch (err){
        console.log(err);
    }
})
```

This is the error that is thrown:

```
error: bind message supplies 1 parameters, but prepared statement "" requires 0
    at Parser.parseErrorMessage (/root/DatabaseApp350/db-class/practice/task4/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:278:15)
    at Parser.handlePacket (/root/DatabaseApp350/db-class/practice/task4/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:126:29)
    at Parser.parse (/root/DatabaseApp350/db-class/practice/task4/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:39:38)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/root/DatabaseApp350/db-class/practice/task4/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/index.js:8:42)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:295:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:271:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:212:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:186:23) {
  length: 137,
  severity: 'ERROR',
  code: '08P01',
  detail: undefined,
  hint: undefined,
  position: undefined,
  internalPosition: undefined,
  internalQuery: undefined,
  where: undefined,
  schema: undefined,
  table: undefined,
  column: undefined,
  dataType: undefined,
  constraint: undefined,
  file: 'postgres.c',
  line: '1665',
  routine: 'exec_bind_message'
}
```

I am not sure how to fix this error! (update error was fixed)

```js
const response = await pool.query(template, [searchTerm]);
```

was changed to:

```js
const response = await pool.query(template);
```

Comment: You are using a parameterized query `pool.query(sql, data)` with no parameters to parse.   Just use `pool.query(sql)` instead.

Comment: That worked! thanks

Comment: Now the page is taking forever to load the /search get request.